# ngTable grouping not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/GExFYJUiT6pn6Q0ii5yN?p=preview) I have an ngTable that contains a list of users, grouped by area. I took the example from [this ngTable grouping demo](http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic). Still, the table is displayed empty and doesn't show any rows or grouping. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <colgroup>
          <col width="50%" />
          <col width="30%" />
          <col width="20%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat-start="group in $groups">
          <td colspan="3">
            <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
              <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
              <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in data" ng-repeat-end>
            <td title="'User ID'">{{ u.uid }}</td>
            <td title="'Name'">{{ u.name }}</td>
            <td title="'Area'" groupable="'area'">{{ u.area }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

          $scope.data = [ 
             { uid: 'User 11', name: 'Name 11', area: 'Area 1'},
             { uid: 'User 12', name: 'Name 12', area: 'Area 1'},
             { uid: 'User 21', name: 'Name 21', area: 'Area 2'},
             { uid: 'User 22', name: 'Name 22', area: 'Area 2'}
          ];

          $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
              // initial grouping
              group: "area"
            },{
              dataset: $scope.data
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems perfectly fine. I have just changed one script and got some results on the page. Just replace

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.8.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

This is the version that I use daily.

Comment: Also `ng-hide="group.$hideRows"` was missing

Comment: Please take a look at this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/M8BcStInfSaSEaq6UVN7?p=preview), the table is not grouping correctly all the items are in both groups

Comment: @ps0604 yeah, you should replace ng-repeat="u in data" with ng-repeat="u in group.data". This way you won't iterate over all elements of a list.

Answer (score 3):

I know the @greenshade answer is done. But as like @greenshade, i have checked that plunker and i see that you have used the old ng-table library link. If you want to work in CDNjs's library then you should use latest script URL:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.js
```

Script src is :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: greenshade suggested to use version 2.0.2, and you suggested to use version 1.0.0, am I missing something?

Comment: @ps0604 Always use the latest version of library .. I m just say you that if you use cdnjs then you should use > 1.0 version library.  Both answers you get are correct. But the way is different to use ng-model library.